# Split strings into lists with Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, io

**Back Story**: I've been struggling with this problem for the last week now, reading through [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), and tutorials online, but I can't figure it out.

I've made a lot of progress with understanding list comprehension and recursion, but this one problem is the one thing still standing in my way.

**Question**: I'm trying to convert a String (or what I think is a String) into a divided list. Here's the code that I have so far (thanks again Jan for the help). It imports the contents of a .txt file.

```
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
     args <- getArgs
     if null args
       then putStrLn "usage: ./pattern dataset.txt"
       else do contents <- readFile $ head args
               putStrLn $ "Filer1: " ++ filterLower(contents)
               convert' contents

filterLower :: String -> String
filterLower st = [ c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A'..'Z']]
```

I tried making my own convert function:

```
convert' :: String -> [String]
convert' x = (x:[])
```

It works, but it doesn't work for this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Error**: This is the error that I regularly get.

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[String]'
    In the return type of a call of `convert''
    In the expression: convert' contents
    In the expression:
      do { contents <- readFile $ head args;
             putStrLn $ "-: " ++ filterLower contents;
           convert' contents }
```

Comment: What is the error/problem that you run into?

Comment: I just added my error into the post.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you call `convert'`? It looks like you're just trying to throw the result away: you don't try to print it or anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "divided string."

Comment: By "divided string" I mean take something like this "A sentence in quotes" and turn it into something like this ["A", "sentence", "in", "a", "list"].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `convert'` is a list of strings, but you're trying to use it as an IO action. You have to do something with the result. For instance,

```
print $ convert' contents
```

would print out the result to the screen. Or you could use, e.g. `mapM_ putStrLn` to print each element out on its own line. Or you could give it a name, and continue writing statements, like:

```
let converted = convert' contents
...
```

Going by your comment, it seems that the way you're trying to divide the string is to turn it into a list of its words, e.g. `convert' "Hello world"` ≡ `["Hello", "world"]`. In that case, you don't need `convert'` at all — the standard `words` function does just that! So you can just use `words contents` and not define `convert'` at all.

Comment: I remember Jan telling me about words, but I didn't realize it was a function. But I should have known by now that everything in Haskell is a function. :D I'm back on track now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SubtleArray, FWIW, it's not true that everything in Haskell is a function. For example, the string `"this is not a function"` is truthful. Only functions are functions ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`convert' :: String -> [String]`, so `convert' contents :: [String]` is just a list of strings. But you have placed it in an IO-block,

```
do contents <- readFile whatever
   putStrLn $ ...
   convert' contents
```

where only expressions of type `IO something` can appear. There's a simple way to make an IO-less expression into an IO thingy, just `return` it:

```
do contents <- readFile ...
   putStrLn $ ...
   return $ convert' contents
```

is correctly typed. But this do-block has type `IO [String]`, so it doesn't match the declared type of `main`. How to fix that depends on what you want your programme to do.

Comment: I see. It's like a C++ function, limited in functionality by its type. Thank you for the clarification. I'm VERY new to Haskell, and I'm still trying to get around the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but the biggest problem is you're not using the `do`-block correctly.  `main` has type `IO ()`, which implies two constraints:

- Every "bare" statement (statement without `<-`) in the do-block must have type `IO a` for some `a`.
- The final statement in the `do`-block must have type `IO ()`; your final statement has type `[String]` (and thus the error you're getting). The simplest statement with that type would be `return ()`.